# Hyperlink or Browser BACK button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to find out what caused the current GET request in ASP.NET (MVC 4 in perticular) ? I need to write server-side code that takes some special actions if the current http GET request is caused by browser's BACK button.

Comment: I looked through the http "Request" object, but did not find anything that tells us if the current browser GET request is caused by browser's BACK button or a hyperlink.

Comment: No. The back button at best only submits a standard GET request for the previous URL again. From the server's standpoint there's no difference between that, clicking a link or typing it directly in the browser. However, many browsers won't even issue a new request to the server when the user clicks the back button, as most keep the previous page in memory. In that case, the server is never even involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript tell the difference between leaving through the back button or a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208129/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-leaving-through-the-back-button-or-a)

Comment: You might also want to check out this link: http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2013/12/browser-back-button-click-event.html